# How can I join strings with a separator in XQuery without having a trailing separator?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

How would one write some XQuery to solve the following:

This is what I have currently written:

```
<friends>
{for $lastname in volunteerDatabase/person/name/lastname
return
concat($lastname/string(), ' +')}
</friends>
```

This query returns:

```
<Friends>Geller + Bing + Tribbiani +</Friends>
```

I would like to return the following where all values are separated by '+':

```
<Friends>Geller + Bing + Tribbiani</Friends>
```

Sample Dummy Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<volunteerDatabase>
<person age="31" ssn="046187254">
    <name>
        <firstname>Ross</firstname>
        <lastname>Geller</lastname>
    </name>
    <telephone type="landline">
        <number>5534567</number>
    </telephone>
    <telephone type="mobile">
        <number>0851234567</number>
    </telephone>
</person>

<person age="29" ssn="355817204">
    <name>
        <firstname>Chandler</firstname>
        <firstname>Muriel</firstname>
        <lastname>Bing</lastname>
    </name>
    <telephone type="mobile">
        <number>0869932617</number>
    </telephone>
</person>

<person ssn="778123666">
    <name>
        <firstname>Joseph</firstname>
        <firstname>Francis</firstname>
        <lastname>Tribbiani</lastname>
    </name>
    <telephone type="landline">
        <number>01628777</number>
    </telephone>
</person>
</volunteerDatabase>
```

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the FLWOR expression:

```
<friends>{fn:string-join(volunteerDatabase/person/name/lastname, " + ")}</friends>
```

...returns, when run with your document as the context item:

```
<friends>Geller + Bing + Tribbiani</friends>
```